# Selecting file logging level on package level

Tags: java, log4j

I have several log files `logfile` and `debugLogFile`. One - more debug info, second less, but still need to have some. In future I expect to have third file with info quantity something between of these two.

I'm asking `log4j` to log package `MyPck` in `INFO` level. This I need for `logfile`. But I need to have `DEBUG` level for `MyPck` for `debugLogFile`. This is a problem.

Both, `logFile` and `debugLogFile` have `Threshold=ALL`. I need to have possibility in each log file to write all level information. For example `logfile` will contain `DEBUG` level for `MyPck` and `INFO` for `MyPck1` and `debugLogFile` will contain `INFO` level for `MyPck` and `DEBUG` for `MyPck1`.  How to solve this problem?

```
log4j.rootLogger=ALL, logfile, debugLogFile
log4j.logger.MyPck=INFO

log4j.appender.logfile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logfile.File=logFile.log
log4j.appender.logfile.Threshold=ALL

log4j.appender.debugLogFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.debugLogFile.File=debugLogFile.log
log4j.appender.debugLogFile.Threshold=ALL
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going in the right direction:

```
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, defaultFile

log4j.appender.defaultFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.defaultFile.File=defaultFile.log

log4j.appender.logfile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logfile.File=logFile.log

log4j.appender.debugLogFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.debugLogFile.File=debugLogFile.log

log4j.logger.MyPck=DEBUG,logFile
log4j.logger.MyPck1=INFO,logFile

log4j.logger.MyPck=INFO,debugLogFile
log4j.logger.MyPck1=DEBUG,debugLogFile

log4j.additivity.MyPck=false
log4j.additivity.MyPck1=false
```

The `log4j.additivity.MyPck=false` setting ensures that the output of MyPck does not appear in the rootLogger appender.

Comment: In this case logFile remains empty. More details in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658150/setting-package-wide-logger-level-via-logger

Answer (score 0):

When you set the log level for `MyPck` to `INFO`, you actually set the *threshold* for this package to `INFO`, i.e. no message below that level will ever be emitted.

So you need to set the threshold of the package to the lowest common level you want to log.

The next step is then to configure the thresholds of the loggers to filter out any messages you don't want:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ALL, logfile, debugLogFile
log4j.logger.MyPck=DEBUG

log4j.appender.logfile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logfile.File=logFile.log
log4j.appender.logfile.Threshold=INFO

log4j.appender.debugLogFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.debugLogFile.File=debugLogFile.log
log4j.appender.debugLogFile.Threshold=DEBUG
```

Note that the second appender gets a copy of all messages of the first one.