# Setting package wide logger level via Logger

Tags: java, log4j

I need to setup system that could log INFO and DEBUG log level information from selected packages (MyPck and MyPck1) to selected files in following way:

```
MyPck DEBUG goes to logFile
MyPck1 INFO goes to logFile

MyPck   INFO goes to debugLogFile
MyPck1 DEBUG goes to debugLogFile
```

I try to do this with lines in Log4j.properties:

```
log4j.logger.MyPck=DEBUG,logFile
log4j.logger.MyPck1=INFO,logFile

log4j.logger.MyPck=INFO,debugLogFile
log4j.logger.MyPck1=DEBUG,debugLogFile
```

Unfortuetly debugLogFile gets info and logFile remains empty. In case if I change lines in log4j.properties according order - first debugLogFile then logFile I will have debugLogFile empty. How to solve this problem?

Whole Log4J.properties settings:

```
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, defaultFile

log4j.appender.defaultFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.defaultFile.File=defaultFile.log
log4j.appender.defaultFile.Threshold=ALL
log4j.appender.defaultFile.MaxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.defaultFile.MaxBackupIndex=4
log4j.appender.defaultFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.defaultFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.defaultFile.Append=false

log4j.appender.logFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logFile.File=logFile.log
log4j.appender.logFile.Threshold=ALL
log4j.appender.logFile.MaxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.logFile.MaxBackupIndex=4
log4j.appender.logFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.logFile.Append=false

log4j.appender.debugLogFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.debugLogFile.File=debugLogFile.log
log4j.appender.debugLogFile.Threshold=ALL
log4j.appender.debugLogFile.MaxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.debugLogFile.MaxBackupIndex=4
log4j.appender.debugLogFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.debugLogFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.debugLogFile.Append=false

log4j.logger.MyPck=DEBUG,logFile
log4j.logger.MyPck1=INFO,logFile

log4j.logger.MyPck=INFO,debugLogFile
log4j.logger.MyPck1=DEBUG,debugLogFile

log4j.additivity.MyPck=false
log4j.additivity.MyPck1=false
```

SOURCE CODE:

Main class:

```
package tst_log4j;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import MyPck.C;
import MyPck1.C1;

public class Tst_Log4J 
{
public final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        C c = new C();
        c.doLog();
        C1 c1 = new C1();
        c1.doLog();
    }
}
```

MyPck class:

```
package MyPck;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class C {
public final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

public void doLog()
    {
    log.info("aaa");
    log.debug("bbb");
    log.error("ccc");

    }


}
```

MyPck1 class:

```
package MyPck1;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class C1 {
public final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

public void doLog()
    {
    log.info("aaa");
    log.debug("bbb");
    log.error("ccc");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create one appender for each scenario and the log out to both.

Give this a go:

```
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, defaultFile

log4j.appender.defaultFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.defaultFile.File=defaultFile.log
log4j.appender.defaultFile.Threshold=ALL
log4j.appender.defaultFile.MaxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.defaultFile.MaxBackupIndex=4
log4j.appender.defaultFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.defaultFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.defaultFile.Append=false

log4j.appender.myPckDebugAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.myPckDebugAppender.File=logFile.log
log4j.appender.myPckDebugAppender.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.myPckDebugAppender.MaxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.myPckDebugAppender.MaxBackupIndex=4
log4j.appender.myPckDebugAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myPckDebugAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.myPckDebugAppender.Append=false

log4j.appender.myPckInfoAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.myPckInfoAppender.File=debugLogFile.log
log4j.appender.myPckInfoAppender.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.myPckInfoAppender.MaxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.myPckInfoAppender.MaxBackupIndex=4
log4j.appender.myPckInfoAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myPckInfoAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.myPckInfoAppender.Append=false

log4j.appender.myPck1DebugAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.myPck1DebugAppender.File=debugLogFile.log
log4j.appender.myPck1DebugAppender.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.myPck1DebugAppender.MaxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.myPck1DebugAppender.MaxBackupIndex=4
log4j.appender.myPck1DebugAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myPck1DebugAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.myPck1DebugAppender.Append=false

log4j.appender.myPck1InfoAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.myPck1InfoAppender.File=logFile.log
log4j.appender.myPck1InfoAppender.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.myPck1InfoAppender.MaxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.myPck1InfoAppender.MaxBackupIndex=4
log4j.appender.myPck1InfoAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myPck1InfoAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.myPck1InfoAppender.Append=false

log4j.logger.MyPck=DEBUG,myPckInfoAppender,myPckDebugAppender
log4j.logger.MyPck1=DEBUG,myPck1InfoAppender,myPck1DebugAppender

log4j.additivity.MyPck=false
log4j.additivity.MyPck1=false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign two log thresholds to a logger.

```
log4j.logger.MyPck=DEBUG,logFile
log4j.logger.MyPck=INFO,debugLogFile
```

is exactly the same as

```
log4j.logger.MyPck=INFO,debugLogFile
```

i.e. the first assignment is overwritten. To get output in both log files, you need:

```
log4j.logger.MyPck=DEBUG,logFile,debugLogFile
```

Comment: but I need INFO from MyPack to debugLogFile and not DEBUG

Comment: That's what you want but to get it, you need to configure log4j correctly. For what you want, you must move the log level filtering to the appenders since you can only have a single log level per logger.